# Concatenate the values from two arrays where the same index is shared

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation, mapping

Here is an example...

I have the following code:

```
$a = array("a", "b", "c");
$b = array("1", "2", "3");

$c = array_merge($a, $b);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($c); 
echo "</pre>";
```

Gives me an output:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

How could I change the code so that it gives me this output instead:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "a','1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "b','2"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "c','3"
```

Comment: What is the purpose ?

Comment: array_combine uses one array for keys and the other for values so wouldn't get the results the @Vytautas has asked for

Comment: yeah, array_combine is quite irrelevant to the asker question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$c = array_map(function ($a, $b) { return "$a','$b"; }, $a, $b);
```

For whatever that's good for...

Answer (score 2):

Using SPL's MultipleIterator:

```
$a = array("a","b","c");
$b = array("1","2","3");

$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($a));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($b));

$c = array();
foreach($mi as $row) {
    $c[] = $row[0] . "','" . $row[1];
}

var_dump($c);
```

Comment: Just having fun, playing a lot with SPL at the moment: you went simple, I've gone complex

Comment: @Vytautas - overkill for this trivial problem; but can do some clever stuff with it when arrays are unequal length, or mismatched keys, or associative/numeric indexes, or you're trying to iterate across a large number of arrays concurrently, etc - http://www.php.net/manual/en/multipleiterator.construct.php

Answer (score 0):

If the keys to both arrays are always in parity, you could do something like

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[] = "$value','{$b[$key]}";
}

var_dump($newArray);
// would output the below
array(3) {
[0]=>
  string(5) "a','1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "b','2"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "c','3"
```

However, the result looks a little weird, are you sure this is what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
$a=array("a","b","c");
$b=array("1","2","3");

if(count($a) > count($b)){
  foreach($a as $key => $value)
      $c[$key] = isset($b[$key])? $value.",".$b[$key] : $value;
} else {
    foreach($b as $key => $value)
      $c[$key] = isset($a[$key])? $a[$key].",".$value : $value;
}
```

Use above code it will for your array.